# External Amazon Turk payment

Tags: jquery, mechanicalturk

I have a survey I want Amazon Turk workers to complete on my website and I want to pay them according to what they answer (This is explained to the workers beforehand).

Is there a way I can get the workers information on my remote website and send a payment request to the Turk based on their worker ID?

Answer (score 0):

the appropriate way to do this is to have a base payment for your Amazon Turk with instructions on how they can achieve a **BONUS**. If you give clear directions on how you will pay them based on an answer then you should achieve the desired effect.

Example:
Hit Base: $0.05
 With Bonus Structure:

- One sentence: $0.10 Bonus
- two sentences: $0.15 Bonus

Etc
How you get their information is to generate a key for them to submit (once the survey is complete) on amazon turk. store that key and match it to the amazon turk submission which will give you the worker ID and whatnot

Answer (score -1):

You'll still need to set something up in MTurk in order to pay them. There's no way to use the MTurk service without creating a HIT and having the workers submit that HIT. You could just have a link to your survey and provide a completion code for workers to submit into MTurk or you could setup an ExternalQuestion-style HIT using the MTurk API, which would simply display your site directly to workers.